# How do I fix the 3-5 second lag when typing with an Apple Bluetooth keyboard on a Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, keyboard

I've been trying to use an Apple Bluetooth Wireless Keyboard with my Windows 7 PC (My own build, not Apple hardware).  If I stop typing for as few as 10-15 seconds, when I start typing again and if I type continuously, there is a lag of 3-5 seconds before the text shows up on the screen. If I type a few keystrokes and then stop, nothing happens. However once I start typing again, all of the previous keystrokes are sent at once.

I'm not sure if this is a driver issue or a problem with my bluetooth adapter.  In Device Manager, it shows 2 Keyboard Devices; 1 on Blutooth HID Device and another on USB Input Device (Logitech Download Assistant).  I am not sure what the Logitech one is. I do have a Logitech Performance MX Mouse, but why that would be under Keyboards, I don't know. Under Bluetooth USB, it shows my Bluetooth adapter from IVT Corporation, Driver Version 6.2.71.213 from June 24, 2010.

How do I fix the 3-5 second lag when typing with an Apple Bluetooth keyboard on a Windows 7 PC?

Answer (score 2):

The frequency of 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi overlaps and can interfere with the Bluetooth frequency that is going to the keyboard to the Mac.

Some PC have better response with this fix:

You just need to go into your Wi-Fi settings by going into the browser and entering the router's IP address (usually "192.168.1.1"). Enter the username and password when prompted. There should be a wireless setting for your wireless frequency, called 'channels' and normally is put the 'automatic' you just have to change that from 'automatic' to 'channel 1' this should out your router to the lowest frequency. After saving the settings just to be sure turn off the router for 30 seconds and check your keyboard if it is working (may need a restart of the iMac and the keyboard). This should resolve the problem.

Comment: This could be a great troubleshooting step and if fixing the channel avoids interference it might also be a great fix. My guess is it depends heavily on the hardware, location and exact nature of the drivers and antennas for both the computer and the keyboard.